# Cannot open zip, compressed, file on external drive with GeoPandas or Fiona, it opens on C drive

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona

I am working with Windows 10 and GeoPandas version '0.4.1' which utilizes Fiona version '1.8.11'

I am trying to open a shapefile from a compressed folder (as described here https://geopandas.org/io.html) on an external hard drive.

my code:

```
gpd.read_file(r"zip:///ecan_data_delete/Waimakariri/Waimakariri/Groundwater/Numerical GW model/input_n_soil_conc.zip!input_n_conc_2018-11-24.shp")
```

returns the following error only when the file is located on an external harddrive (e.g. zip file path "D:\ecan_data_delete\Waimakariri\Waimakariri\Groundwater\Numerical GW model\input_n_soil_conc.zip"):

```
fiona.errors.DriverError: '/vsizip//ecan_data_delete/Waimakariri/Waimakariri/Groundwater/Numerical GW model/input_n_soil_conc.zip/input_n_conc_2018-11-24.shp' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

when I make a copy of the zip file on my local drive (e.g. create "C:\ecan_data_delete\Waimakariri\Waimakariri\Groundwater\Numerical GW model\input_n_soil_conc.zip")
it runs perfectly, which means that fiona is assuming that the file (and therefore I believe the virtual file) is on the C drive.

Is it possible to fix this?  I have spent some time looking through the documentation, but it is pretty light here (and/or above my understanding).  I know that I could simply move the zipped file over to my C drive, but I am running through a bunch of shape files zipped up with some big modelling files on a hard drive and making some quick figures to see what is there, so moving it is not a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted does not specify the 'D:' drive anywhere (and implicitly specifies the 'C:' drive).  Python is not a Windows-specific language and `zip:///` refers to the root file system (in URL format, `zip` is the protocol, `://` the protocol/resource separator, and `/` is the root file system).

On Windows the root file system would normally be 'C:/'.

If you want to specify the similar path on the 'D:' drive instead of on the 'C:' drive, you have to explicitly tell it to use the 'D:' drive.  Try it like this:

`gpd.read_file(r"zip://D:/ecan_data_delete/Waimakariri/Waimakariri/Groundwater/Numerical GW model/input_n_soil_conc.zip!input_n_conc_2018-11-24.shp")`

Comment: Hi This worked.  I had previously played around with various path options, but it was never clear to me.  Thank you

Comment: @MatthewHanson don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your question.

Comment: thanks I'm relatively new here :)